# How to work with HTTPS request in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery ajax for authenticating username and password, however due to security reason I need to call HTTPS request.

Below is my **JQuery Code:** where I need to implement the HTTPS call.

```
 //Submitting the form
$("#loginDetails > form").submit(function()
{  
    //Hiding the Login button
    $("#loginButton").hide();

    //Showing the ajax loading image
    $("#ajaxloading").show();

    // 'this' refers to the current submitted form  
    var str = $(this).serialize();   
    // -- Start AJAX Call --

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login.aspx",  // Send the login info to this page
        data: str,  
        success: function(result)
        {  

            $("#loginDetails").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {  

             // Show 'Submit' Button
            $('#loginButton').show();

            // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
            $('#ajaxloading').hide();  

            var resLength = result.trim().length;

            if(resLength!=0)
            {
                var arr = result.split(",");
                var fname = arr[0];
                var lname = arr[1];
                var activeCardNo = arr[2];
                var multipleTier = arr[3];
                var activeStatus = arr[4];
                var access = arr[5];

                 if(access!='' && access!='undefined') // LOGIN OK?
                 { 
                     $('.validateTips').hide();
                    var login_response = '<div id="logged_in">' +
                     '<div style="width: 350px; float: left; margin-left: 80px;">' + 
                     '<div style="width: 40px; float: left;">' +
                     '<img style="margin: 22px 0px 10px 0px;" align="absmiddle" src="system/images/ajax-loader.gif">' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div style="margin: 24px 0px 0px 10px; float: right; width: 300px;">'+ 
                     "You are successfully logged in! <br /> Please wait while you're redirected...</div></div>";  

                    $('#loginButton').hide();
                    $('#closeBtn').hide();
                    $('#divMember').text(fname +' '+ lname);
                    $('#spnSkywardsNo').text(activeCardNo);
                    $('#spnTierStatus').text(multipleTier);
                    $("#ui-dialog-title-skywardsLogin").text(getDataFromResourceFile('pleaseWait'));

                    $('#divSuccessLogin').html(login_response);
                    $('#divSuccessLogin').show();
                    $('#loginDetails').hide();
                    //$(this).html(login_response); // Refers to 'status'

                    // After 3 seconds redirect the 
                    setTimeout(closeDialog, 3000); 

                 }  
              }
            else// ERROR?
             {  
                 var login_response = getDataFromResourceFile('InvalidUsername');
                 $('.validateTips').html(login_response);
             }

     });  

     }  

    });  

    // -- End AJAX Call --

    return false; 
});
```

The above code works perfect, but due to security issues, I need to change my call call to **HTTPS**, so my ajax call will not be **"Login.aspx"** it will be **"https://login.aspx"**

Please suggest how to achieve this, so that my security is maintained and there will not be any security conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen by default if the *page* is `https://`, this *has* to be the case...you can't make an AJAX request from an `http://` page to an `https://` destination, and vice-versa.  When you try this, it's seen as a different protocol, and in violating of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), so you'll be prevented from seeing the response.

Comment: Can you please clear it, so what I understand with above wordings that, if the page is HTTPS then it will automatically be handled and there will not be security violations, if possible please suggest with some examples..thanks

Comment: @Nick: Well, you *can* do it -- using [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) or [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) -- but you have to do it on purpose. :-)

Comment: @T.J. - that's not an AJAX request :)

Comment: @MKS: If the page itself was requested and served via `https`, then anything relative to it (for instance, the URL `Login.aspx`) will also be requested and served via `https`. No need for you to do anything special. It's only if you have a page served insecurely (`http`) that you would have to make a special effort to handle anything else via `https`.

Comment: @MKS - that's correct, if the page is `https://` and your path is relative (e.g. `Login.aspx` like you have, or `/path/Login.aspx`, not `http://site.com/Login.aspx`) then the request is also `https://`, it'll stay on the same protocol.

Comment: @Nick: CORS is. True that JSON-P isn't.

Comment: Thanks Guys, so I don't need to take any precautions in above code if I have got https://login.aspx page with me.

Comment: @MKS - correct, just keep it relative like you already have and you'll stay on `https` :)